# Ввод данных через консоль используя Scanner

Tags: java

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How much money do you have?");
double money = console.nextDouble();
System.out.println(money);
```

Почему при вводе данных в консоль, например 100 * 5, получается не 500.0, а ошибка?

Comment: Потому что строка "100 * 5" - это не число двойной точности 500.0

Comment: То есть, 100 не умножается на 5, а затем получается число 500.0?

Comment: Нет, не умножается. Для JVM - это просто строка, не имеющая вообще никакого смысла. Чтобы умножилось, нужно выполнить лексический анализ строки, потом выполнить синтаксический анализ полученных токенов, а после вычислить полученное выражение. В одну строку вам этого не добиться.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/how-to-evaluate-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form Здесь есть пример, как можно вычислить выраженте из строки

Answer (score 1):

А где ошибка у вас получается, в IDE? У вас должно захватываться только первое число - это либо 100, если вы вводите 100 * 5, либо 5, если вы вводите 5 * 100.

Метод `nextDouble()` захватывает первое число слева, а всё, что после пробела - он игнорирует.

Поэтому на выводе у вас должна быть не ошибка, а 100.00 либо 5.00.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том что при вводе тебе необходимо указать число, а не операцию. При вводе через Scanner тебе необходимо указать лишь число double в данном случае, а затем можно просто дописать код.

```java
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How much money do you have?");
double money = console.nextDouble();
money = money *5;
System.out.println(money);
```

Comment: То есть, Scanner не может выполнять операции, правильно?

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` принимает значения, а не выполняет функции. В случае с `nextDouble()` `Scanner` ожидает `double-значение`. Ошибка выпадать не должна, так как `nextDouble()`считывает первое значение и в консоль выводить его. Чтобы все выполнялось правильно, нужно сделать это:

```
double money = console.nextDouble();
money = money * 5;
```